# Truncated Cylinder

Tags: geometry

I am doing an ottoman in wood. The shape is a truncated cylinder. What I need is to be able to cut the wall in thin wood to wrap it around the truncated cylinder.
I know it can be made from a semi circumference but I haven't been able to find a formula to do so. I am attaching an sketch of what I want to do. [Current Truncated Cylinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4n9B.jpg) . I found this [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD8ew.png) but the formula does not work.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: The two disks have different radii, so it seems to be a truncated cone.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are looking for the area of the grey fan-shape shaded region.

Let OAB be a sector of a circle (centered at O with radius = R). If its arc AB is of length P, then the area of the sector OAB is $\dfrac {RP}{2}$.

Therefore, the required area = 
$$\dfrac {(r’ + sL)(\pi D)}{2} - \dfrac {(r’)(\pi d)}{2} = \dfrac {\pi (Dr’ + DsL – dr’)}{2}$$; where, $sL = \sqrt {(\dfrac {D}{2} - \dfrac {d}{2})^2 + h^2}.$

Answer (score 0):

Probably in your diagram you did not compute $r'$ correctly (it is not one of your radii)

Assume that radii are $r<R$ and the height is $h$. Then the lateral surface of the corresponding truncated cone is given by a sector of an annulus (like in your diagram) with internal radius 
$$r'=\frac{r\sqrt{(R-r)^2+h^2}}{R-r},$$
and external radius
$$sL+r'=\frac{R\sqrt{(R-r)^2+h^2}}{R-r}.$$
Let me know if the diagram works with the above formulas.

Comment: @Gio Any further doubt?